# Dictionary and Array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello i am pretty new to Node.js and i stumble upon one problem with dictionary and array. And what i want to is to access, courseid, coursename.

```html
 data = [
    {
        name: "Ole Nordmann",
        pin: 1331,
        Job: "Yes",
        AccountNumber: 1234,
        income: 50000,
        loan: 1000,
        Savings: 10000000,
        Balance: 5500,
        TransactionHistory: [
            { courseid: "CS654", coursename: "Introduction to Programming", credithours: 7.5 }, 
            { courseid: "CS081", coursename: "Database Management", credithours: 7.5 },
            { courseid: "CS943", coursename: "System Design", credithours: 7.5 }

        ]

    }
```

Comment: i want something like this

CS654 Introduction to programming
CS081 Database Management
CS943 System Design.

Comment: Hello @JoyfulReindeer, Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question to include what approaches you have taken and what error you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `find` a method, where u can pass `callback` function to match.

```js
data = [
  {
      name: "Ole Nordmann",
      pin: 1331,
      Job: "Yes",
      AccountNumber: 1234,
      income: 50000,
      loan: 1000,
      Savings: 10000000,
      Balance: 5500,
      TransactionHistory: [
          { courseid: "CS654", coursename: "Introduction to Programming", credithours: 7.5 }, 
          { courseid: "CS081", coursename: "Database Management", credithours: 7.5 },
          { courseid: "CS943", coursename: "System Design", credithours: 7.5 }
      ]
  }
]

const findUserByName = (name, data = []) => {
  return data.find(user => user.name === name)
}
const findUserByCourseId = (courseid, data = []) => {
  return data.find(user => user.TransactionHistory.some(history => history.courseid === courseid))
}
console.log(findUserByName("Ole Nordmann", data))
console.log(findUserByCourseId("CS654", data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your issue. Hope it'll help

According to your requirement i've also added the `setCourseInfo` function to add new course.

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "Ole Nordmann",
    pin: 1331,
    Job: "Yes",
    AccountNumber: 1234,
    income: 50000,
    loan: 1000,
    Savings: 10000000,
    Balance: 5500,
    TransactionHistory: [
      {
        courseid: "CS654",
        coursename: "Introduction to Programming",
        credithours: 7.5,
      },
      {
        courseid: "CS081",
        coursename: "Database Management",
        credithours: 7.5,
      },
      { courseid: "CS943", coursename: "System Design", credithours: 7.5 },
    ],
  },
];

const getCourseInfo = (data) => {
  return data[0]["TransactionHistory"].reduce((courseInfo, course) => {
    return (courseInfo += `${course.courseid} ${course.coursename}\n`);
  }, ``);
};

const setCourseInfo = (newCourseData) => {
  data[0]["TransactionHistory"].push(newCourseData);
}

console.log(getCourseInfo(data));
const newCourseData = {
 courseid: 2323,
 coursename: "This is a test ",
 credithours: 32
}
setCourseInfo(newCourseData);
console.log('-----after adding new course----');
console.log(getCourseInfo(data));
```

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot ! But i got a nother problem is that what if i want to add new things to the dictionary. For instance  i want to add a new course 

courseid = 2323, coursename = "This is a test ", credithours = 32.

Comment: @JoyfulReindeer ok, i've added that too. Would you please check now? Also if this helps you then please don't forget to mark this as accepted answer. That'll help others too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access course ID and course Name in the following way:

```
    var courseId = data[0].TransactionHistory[0].courseid
    var courseName = data[0].TransactionHistory[0].coursename
```

To access all the data in the Array, write a **for loop**:

```
    function a() {
      var result = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (var j=0; j< data[i].TransactionHistory.length; j++) {
          var item = data[i].TransactionHistory;
          result = result + item[j].courseid + " " + item[j].coursename + "\n";
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
```

The result variable (returned by function a) will have the courseid and coursename details.